# Filter values inside Python generator expressions

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have a dictionary `dct` for which I want each of its values to be summed provided their corresponding keys exist in a specified list `lst`.

The code I am using so far is:

```
sum(dct[k] for k in lst)
```

In the above generator expression I would like to handle the `KeyError` in case a key from the list is not found inside the dictionary. I cannot seem to find how to implement (syntax-wise) either a `try`-`except` approach, nor an `if`-`else` approach inside this generator expression.

In case a *key from the list is not found inside the dictionary, then it should carry on getting the other values*. *The end result of the sums should not be affected by any missing keys*. In case none of the keys exist, then zero should be the sum's result.

Comment: You can't use `try` in a generator expression. Why not use `dct.get(k)`, which will give you `None` instead of an error if the key isn't found? What is the correct behaviour for your code in the case where a key isn't found (e.g. should it count as `0`)?

Comment: If a key is not found then it should carry on with the remaining keys. (I will update my description to explain this case - thanks for noting this)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are few options, preferred one is to use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
# 1
sum(dct.get(k, 0) for k in lst)
# 2
sum(dct[k] for k in lst if k in dct)
```

Also one of the option is to filter `lst` before iteraring over it:

```
sum(dct[k] for k in filter(lambda i: i in dct, lst))
```

And you can use [reduce function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) on filtered list as an alternative to `sum`:

```
reduce(lambda a, k: a + dct[k], filter(lambda i: i in dct, lst))
```

Now let's find fastest approach with [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

```
from timeit import timeit
import random

lst = range(0, 10000)
dct = {x:x for x in lst if random.choice([True, False])}

via_sum = lambda:(sum(dct.get(k, 0) for k in lst))
print("Via sum and get: %s" % timeit(via_sum, number=10000))
# Via sum and get: 16.725695848464966

via_sum_and_cond = lambda:(sum(dct[k] for k in lst if k in dct))
print("Via sum and condition: %s" % timeit(via_sum_and_cond, number=10000))
# Via sum and condition: 9.4715681076

via_reduce = lambda:(reduce(lambda a, k: a + dct[k], filter(lambda i: i in dct, lst)))
print("Via reduce: %s" % timeit(via_reduce, number=10000))
# Via reduce: 19.9522120953
```

So the fastest option is to sum items via if statement within generator expression

```
sum(dct[k] for k in lst if k in dct) # Via sum and condition: 9.4715681076
```

**Good Luck !**

Comment: Great and complete answer. Curious if you could offer some insight in comparing these 4 options; specifically, how the 3rd option compares to the first two. Is there any efficiency gains or a more 'Pythonic' approach among them?

Comment: @Yannis thanks,  sure ) see updated answer with time metrics :) My guess  winner method is most 'Pythonic' to )

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

Checking if the key exists

```
sum(dct[k] for k in lst if k in dct)
```

or using `get`

```
sum(dct.get(k, 0) for k in lst)
```

where `dct.get(k, 0)` returns `dct[k]` if `k` is a key in `dct` or `0` if not.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(dct[k] for k in lst if k in dct)
```

Comment: Helpful answer indeed; other people mentioned this approach as well and from what I can see, yours was not the fastest one. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to attempt to get the value for the key from the dictionary, and should it not be found will return `None`, or your provided default parameter which would be 0 in this case.

```
>>> dct = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
>>> lst = [1,5]
>>> sum(dct.get(k, 0) for k in lst)
8
```

Should some (*or all*) of the keys not exist, the sum will still function properly.

```
>>> lst = [10, 11]
>>> sum(dct.get(k, 0) for k in lst)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get`-method of dictionaries, to provide a default value if not found:

```
sum(dct.get(k, 0) for k in lst)
```