# Creating a function inside a class with self variables as arguments (Python)

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, self

Inside a class I want to create a method that would have as arguments some `self.` variables.

For example (some code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772551/filter-values-inside-python-generator-expressions#37772746)), say that I have

```
class Summations(object):
    dct = {'A': 11, 'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'D': 12, 'E': 5, 'L': 2, 'M': 0, 'Z': 9}

    f_lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
    s_lst = ['H', 'I', 'J']
    t_lst = ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N']

    def get_results(self):
        # Sum each of the dictionary's values provided their corresponding keys exist in a specified list.

        f_sum = sum(self.dct.get(k, 0) for k in self.f_lst)
        s_sum= sum(self.dct.get(k, 0) for k in self.s_lst)
        t_sum= sum(self.dct.get(k, 0) for k in self.t_lst)
```

I am trying to avoid the repeated code from all the summations inside the `get_results` and create a separate class method to handle these summations, something like this:

```
def do_sums(self, d, l):
    return sum(self.d(k, 0) for k in self.l)
```

and have the `do_sums` be called inside the `get_results` like so

```
f_sum = self.do_sums(self, dct, f_lst)
s_sum = self.do_sums(self, dct, s_lst)
t_sum = self.do_sums(self, dct, t_lst)
```

Is something like this (self variables of a class used as arguments in that classe's method) even possible? And if yes, how will the syntax look like?

Comment: I would recommend following a structured OOP Python tutorial; you don't just throw `self` in everywhere and hope for the best! Think about which things are *attributes* of the object you're building, and which should be passed around as *parameters* of its methods.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand what you mean and I can see how my question is very naive, to say the least. But it was the only way I could some guideline and hints since I am a newbie in programming and Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getattr()` to access attributes dynamically; give the object to look the attribute on (`self` here) and a string with the name of the attribute:

```
def do_sums(self, d, l):
    return sum(getattr(self, d).get(k, 0) for k in getattr(self, l))
```

and pass in *names*:

```
f_sum = self.do_sums('dct', 'f_lst')
s_sum = self.do_sums('dct', 's_lst')
t_sum = self.do_sums('dct', 't_lst')
```

There is no need to pass in `self` since `self.do_sums()` is a bound method.

But you already know your attributes when you call the method, so you could just pass in the objects directly:

```
def do_sums(self, d, l):
    return sum(d.get(k, 0) for k in l)
```

and pass in the `self.dct` and list objects:

```
f_sum = self.do_sums(self.dct, self.f_lst)
s_sum = self.do_sums(self.dct, self.s_lst)
t_sum = self.do_sums(self.dct, self.t_lst)
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Not only it works but also highlights the shortcomings in approach and programming skills. thanks

Comment: Small follow-up question; do you reckon that using the `do_sums` and pass in the `self.dct` and list objects (your 2nd suggestion) is better in terms of efficiency and code duplication compared to not using any such `do_sums` method and implementing as I describe in my first code block??

Comment: @nk-fford: there isn't really much difference here as the `do_sums` function is rather small.